# qui and its different uses

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-interrogatifs

My french teacher recently told me that the interrogative qui can be used both as an interrogate as well as taking the place of a pronoun. Why is this and what is the linguistic reason?

Comment: This is also true for the Wh-words in English. They can be used as interrogative pronouns (_Which one did you prefer?_) or as relative pronouns (_I also liked the one which you preferred_). This is in general true of words in Indo-European languages that come from [the PIE root **kʷo-*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=kʷo-), like the Qu-words in Romance Languages.